# Missing $ Inserted error thrown in a custom command

Tags: macros

This is my first post on this community. I am fairly new to latex and have added a custom function using `\newcommand`. The command is as follows -

```
\newcommand{\addQuestion}[6]{
    \textbf{#1}. #2
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alpha*)]
    \item #3
    \item #5
    \item #4
    \item #6
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
}
```

and my document is as -

```
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\addQuestion{Q27}{a sample question}{This}{That}{this}{that}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The Error is thrown on the line with `\addQuestion` which says

```
xAssignment.tex.swp:23: Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.23 ...a sample question}{This}{That}{this}{that}
```

I did browse through the previous posts but found nothing helpful. Could anyone please help me with this.
TIA

Comment: `\alpha` is a math command, you probably mean `\alph*`. Side remark: I would avoid to define commands with 6 arguments, that is normally too much, and difficult to remember.

Comment: Not related, but why do you use `multicols{2}` into your `\addQuestion` command AND outside your command call in the body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get an alphabetic numbering, you should type `\alph`; `\alpha` is the command to create the Greek letter α, which only works in math mode.

Note that you did not post a Minimal Working Example. I had to guess that you were using both the `multicol` and the `enumitem` packages. This will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\addQuestion}[6]{
    \textbf{#1}. #2
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item #3
    \item #5
    \item #4
    \item #6
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
  }
\begin{document}
\addQuestion{Q27}{a sample question}{This}{That}{this}{that}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jose Calrlos Santos. I never would have caught that typo